# Burning [sheet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) has no wiki, 1 follower, and <s>174</s> <s>246</s> 175 questions.

Questions in the tag ranging from [sprite animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331253/sprite-sheet-failed) to [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768900/delete-excel-sheet-not-in-list) to [Cocoa development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561347/cant-edit-nstextfield-in-sheet-at-runtime).  About 100 of its questions are tagged [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), or both.

Can we burninate this tag?

Comment: I read "Burning [skeet]" and was shocked...

Comment: Jeez @Will, are you three [tag:sheet]s to the wind or what? ;)

Comment: @honk I read something more crappy. *Ahem...*

Answer (score 7):

Since all the questions have been cleaned up, we can declare this [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet):

[image: puff the magic dragon]

Good work, everyone!

---

Yes, please!

I posted [Delete the [sheet] tag on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179715/delete-the-sheet-tag-on-stack-overflow) in Sept 2013. I regularly replace it with more specific tags on questions I run across, but I think a small group effort could eliminate it.

**There are now <s>136</s> 0 [questions tagged [sheet]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet).**

These questions frequently have other weak / ambiguous tags that should be removed or replaced. Watch for:

- No use whatsoever, clean them off while you're at it: [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell)
- [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) should be replaced with [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula), [lotus-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus-formula), [array-formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-formulas) or [formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas) (with an **S**). Questions about spreadsheet formulas should have one of these tags.

Here are some queries that provide lists of questions that can be easily cleaned up, because they already have more specific tags on them:

- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) <s>106</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet%20excel)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) <s>25</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet%20google-spreadsheet)
  (Add [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) if the question includes script.)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [libreoffice-calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-calc) <s>2</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-calc%20sheet)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) <s>32</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba%20sheet)
  (Specialize [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) by adding sub-tag [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) or [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac) as appropriate.)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) <s>26</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba%20sheet)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + "php" <s>10</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sheet]+php+is%3Aquestion)
- [sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sheet) + [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) <s>6</s> 0 questions [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sheet]+[jquery]+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Well, all but the only one with an accepted answer will be swept away by the roomba anyway, by now. Preempting that with delete-votes, whatever.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm disappointed to note that those questions got downvoted during the close-vote process. It's true that the Roomba will eventually get them  - but that wasn't the plan.